# Move bootable partition to another disk

Tags: windows, hard-drive, boot, ssd, windows-8.1

I have laptop which came with HDD drive. Now i need to upgrade it with SSD by keeping HDD and replace CD ROM with Hard disk bay+SSD.

I'm bored to re-install windows and software in new drive. Therefore i need to move C: and D: drives permanently into new drive without loosing files (clone C: and D partitions into new drives and boot with it).

How can i do this ? Are there any drawbacks or issues ?

Comment: I googled this a bit and this is what i found : http://lifehacker.com/5837543/how-to-migrate-to-a-solid-state-drive-without-reinstalling-windows This is supposed to be what you are looking for, i did not test it myself so be careful

Answer (score 1):

This is highly not recommended and most likely such a setup will fail because of different discrepancies in Windows' configuration. You either reinstall the OS on your new drive or you use it as a data drive if you want to avoid problems.